# No MFC templates available for a new C++ project - Visual C++ Express

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++-2010-express

i've been googling before posting this but i havent been able to find anything on the topic.. yet i dont think its a very tricky one so please forgive for posting :o).

for a new job i am getting into C++, and following some tutorials. in particular one is about MFC, it shows how to create a project , selecting MFC application and so on. So, i installed Visual C++ Express 2010 on both a vista and a Win 7, and both time i had the same issue: when i go to new project , I have no "MFC" menu . some screenshots from that tutorial , and from some other on Visual C++ 2010 clearly show that it can be there. to be more specific, on corner left I have "installed templates" , then "Visual C++" and "CLR", Win32" and "General" , no MFC.

as these are "installed templates", i guess i should have to install it, but i found no clear indication on the topic; from what i found it should more or less be there from the beginning ... i also found a way to add MFC DLL through creating a Win32 application, but it doesnt seem its exactly the same thing .. I spent also some time on the menus of Visual C++ but did not find any clear way to add new templates like in Eclipse...

Well, I hope I made myself clear, i think this is pretty basic but if anyone could give me a hand on that one i'd greatly appreciate.

Cheers
Vincent

Comment: Only Visual Studio Pro and superior have MFC.

Comment: Hi you can try add mfc project like in this article [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/MFCinVisualStudioExpress.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/MFCinVisualStudioExpress.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio C++ Express does not support creating MFC applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you don`t mind the leaking of unicode support, you can downlaod the visual studio 2013 express for desktop and install the free mfc mbcs support[from microsoft.com](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/2/3/02389126-40A7-46FD-9D83-802454852703/vc_mbcsmfc.exe)